# Android set text of TextInputLayout in listener

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a form in a dialog fragment. One of the fields open a custom date picker dialog, which returns the selected date via `setFragmentResult()`. I want to set this date as the value of the given text field.

When I create the dialog fragment, which contains the form, I can change the value of the given field using `getEditText().setText()`, but the same thing does not work in the `FragmentResultListener`.

I have tried to use both view binding and `findViewById()`.

**DateDialog**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DialogDateBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());
    dialogBuilder.setView(binding.getRoot());
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Select", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString("bundleKey", "DATE_STRING"); // it's just temporary
            getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("request_key", result);
        }
    });

    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
```

**DialogFragment**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DialogPatientBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

    binding.date.getEditText().setText("SOMETHING"); // it works!

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());
    dialogBuilder.setView(binding.getRoot());

    binding.date.getEditText().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DateDialog dateDialog = new DateDialog();
            dateDialog.show(getParentFragmentManager(), "date_dialog");
        }
    });

    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("request_key", getActivity(), new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
            String value = result.getString("bundle_key");

            Log.d("TEST", result.getString(value)); //logs "DATE_STRING"
            binding.date.getEditText().setText(value); // does not work
            ((TextInputLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.date)).getEditText().setText(value); // does not work
        }
    });

    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
```

Comment: Where do you implement the `setFragmentResultListener` exactly? In `onCreateView` or somewhere else?

Comment: @Kozmotronik In `onCreateDialog`.

Comment: The code you provide is not enough to help us to see or debug the error. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: What is the difference between `binding.date.getEditText().setText()` and `binding.date.setText()`? What `date` object type? Is it a `TextInputLayout`?

Comment: `date` is a `TextInputLayout`. It does not have a `setText` method.

Comment: _date is a TextInputLayout. **It does not have a setText method**_.   
I think you caught the bug!

Comment: Nope, it was just an error in the sample code. I've fixed it. `binding.date.getEditText().setText()` should work, but it only works outside of the listener.

Comment: You don't say :(. Now it's time for some test in android studio. Here I go...

Comment: @Kozmotronik I think I've just solved it. I will test it, and let you know.

Comment: Great! Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used view binding in both `onCrateView` and `onCreateDialog`.

```
private DialogBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // instead of this
    binding = DialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    return view;

    // do this
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DialogBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());  // do it here
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder dialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());
    dialogBuilder.setView(binding.getRoot());
    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
```

In the fragment lifecycle `onCreateDialog` runs first, then `onCreateView`. I guess the binding in `onCreateView` created a new object, and I lost the reference to the original one.

Possibly an amateur mistake. But if anyone faces the same problem, just don't do it in both methods! Just use `inflater.inflate()` in `onCreateView`!